# Как в БД безопасно хранить пароли от пользовательских мейлов?

Tags: django, postgresql

Всем здравствуйте!

**Проект:** простой сервис email-рассылок. Пользователи могут создавать несколько рассылок и к каждой подгружать разные мейлы, с которых и будет производиться рассылка.

**Вопрос:** как безопасно хранить пароли от этих почт? Ведь, если я их захэширую, то не смогу авторизоваться под ними в процессе рассылки.

Comment: Хранимые процедуры, которые доступны только на исполнение. Таблица с паролями, в принципе недоступная никому, кроме процедур. Всё собственно.

Comment: @Akina понял, поизучаю, спасибо!

Comment: В системе хранения резервных копий у вас тогда будут пароли доступны в открытом виде, и доступны администраторам, это все таки персональные данные я надеялся что то более продвинутое увидеть. По моему мнению шифровать нужно все равно и хранить в зашифрованном виде, разделить отвественность за хранение используемых ключей и зашифрованных данных дистанцировав их друг от друга это усложнит доступ.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov `разделить отвественность за хранение используемых ключей и зашифрованных данных дистанцировав их друг от друга это усложнит доступ.` вот это не очень понятно - можно поподробнее про реализацию  такого подхода? Или где это можно почитать? Спасибо

Comment: Мы с коллегой ломали голову над этой проблемой, в итоге на уровне бизнеслогики и нас есть алгоритм который запрашивает с сервера БД ряд потенциально неизменных данных о самом сервере и пользователе (последнее не обязаельно). Используя ряд преобразований мы генерируем соль,  шифруем пароли сохраняем их в таблицу. Получается алгоритм шифрования в среднем уровне на вебсервере а все исходные данные и результаты шифрования на серверах СУБД. Даже если у вас один сервер без анализа кода понять как выполняется шифрование затруднительно. Это уже не мидл админ. Вообще это война брони и снаряда. всегда.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov понял, благодарю за развернутый ответ

Comment: Я не очень понимаю что конкретно вы делаете, но если говорить о действительно развернутом ответе, то автоматические рассылки от имени физических пользоватлей это плохая практика и это должно быть согласовано при регистрации отдельно, так как подобное публичное использование имени без выраженного согласия противозаконно. Все мыллеры работают от имени сервера или авторизатора в зависимости от схемы но не от зарегистрированного физического лица.